# Find best Offer from List - Lambda possible?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, refactoring, code-cleanup

I was just writing this little code to find the cheapest offer out of a list and I'm wondering if this could be written more elegant with some lambda-function?

```java
private Offer getBestOffer(List<Offer> allOffers, int amount) {
    Offer bestOffer = null;
    BigDecimal bestPrice = null;
    for (Offer offer : allOffers) {

        BigDecimal unitCosts = offer.getUnitPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(amount));
        BigDecimal completePrice = offer.getBasicCosts().add(unitCosts);

        if (bestPrice == null || completePrice.compareTo(bestPrice) == -1) {
            bestOffer = offer;
            bestPrice = completePrice;
        }
    }
    return bestOffer;
}
```

Or is this not really a good use case for a lambda-function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with this logic, and then stream the `allOffers` list and get its minimum according to that `Comparator`:

```java
private static Offer getBestOffer(List<Offer> allOffers, int amount) {
    Comparator<Offer> cmp =
        Comparator.comparing(o -> 
            o.getBasicCosts().add(o.getUnitPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(amount))));

    return allOffers.stream().min(cmp).orElse(null);
}
```